# "so far as" vs. "as far as"

Tags: difference

Tell me please if these phrases have identical meanings in the following sentences.

> **So far as** I know this is the fastest car in the world.
>
> **As far as** I know this is the fastest car in the world.

I have checked the phrases in various dictionarie, and still I cannot see any difference. Is there any?

Comment: They are the same.  I believe this has been asked before on ELL.  If I recall the "so far as" is a more recent variation on "as far as", mixing together two related idioms.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

They mean exactly the same thing.